# Borderlands 2 First SMG

Tags: borderlands-2

After playing BL2 on the PC through Steam with two different characters in three separate games. I played up to level seven roughly.

I cannot find/buy any SMGs. So, wondering if anyone else has come across this phenomenon. I've googled and didn't find anything, further to this since loot is random guns don't really have locations.

**When do SMGs come later in the game? 
Or have I just not come across any yet?**

Thanks for you time.

Comment: I can't help but think removing the "When did you find your first SMG?" would help reduce downvoting. That one sentence will strike some as polling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah they come a tad bit later, don't worry about it. Once you come to Sanctuary and start doing quests from that point you'll be getting lots of SMG's as drops and they will be available in the shops.

Answer (score 4):

I can't remember when I did find my first SMG, but I'm certain that SMGs drop in the "later game". I can't tell you whether there is an area/level/progression restriction and I can't tell you exactly when they "start to drop".

Maybe it's just you having no luck in finding any, I had the same going for sniper rifles until I hit level 11.

Comment: I'd say that level 11 is a pretty good estimate. My friend and I are level 14, and we see quite a few SMGs/sniper rifles now, but until a few levels ago we couldn't find any.